# Combining Angular Filters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have strings that I would like to:

a) automatically link urls (linky)

b) convert new lines to <br>

c) strip all other html except the links and new lines

```
i.e. - "A\nB\n\C\nhttp://www.angularjs.org<p>Foo</p>" becomes "A<br/>B<br/>C<br/><a href='http://www.angularjs.org'>http://www.angularjs.org</a>Foo"

filter('newlines', function() {
    return function(text) {
        return text.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
    }
})

filter('unsafe', function($sce) {
    return function(val) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
    };
})

filter('noHTML', function() {
    return function(text) {
        if(text == null){
            return "";
        }
        return text.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/</g, '&lt;');
    }
})

<span ng-bind-html="p.body | noHTML | newlines | linky | unsafe"></span>
```

produces does everything but properly output the breaks  - these are being rendered as text

Comment: I created a jsbin with this code (minus the linky filter) and it seems like it works fine: http://jsbin.com/menaqime/1/edit

Comment: @aet I think he wants the link to be enclosed by the `<a>` tag. I think it's rather dubious how OP says everything works but the line breaks. I've a feeling that `linky` would eat into the `<p>Foo</p>` part of the content to filter, thus leaving you with an invalid link anyway (i.e. simply try logging the output of `{{p.body | linky}}` to see what I mean).